# CSS polygonal image map :hover/rollover

Tags: image, dictionary, hover, polygon

I came up with a (what I thought was simple) navigation to use on a wordpress install.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/441/navlfz.png/

When making most of my nav menus I create a sprite and use a list. But, I can't use typical rectangular sprites, so I'll have to use a polygonal image map, HOWEVER I can't figure out how to change the background image for the hover state.  Anyone run into this and can point me in the right direction?

Or am I barking up the wrong tree?  Maybe there's an easier solution.